# SQL query to get most recent row

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

I have a Student History table which maintains the enrolled section history for each student. For example, Student X is presently in Section 1 and Student X may have been in other sections in the past (including past enrollment in Section 1).

Each time Student X changes to another section a record is added to the Student History table.

The Student History table has following structure:
`Student Id`, `Date_entered`, `section_id`

I need to write a SQL query to get the records for the following scenario:

Get `Student Id` of all students CURRENTLY in Sections 1 & 2 (Students most recent `date_entered` must have been either Sections 1 or 2). The results should not include any students who were in these sections 1 & 2 in the past.

Sample Query:

```
select student_id from student_Queue_history where section_id in (1, 2)
```

Can someone help me write query for this one?

Comment: how do you determine the "past" termine? Do you have the date_finished field in the history table or something else?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any other fields....  I have only date_entered column related to this dates... If student X moved to another section, then table will get new record with new section_id and new date_entered..  If the most date_entered record has section 5 for student X, we can take it as he is not present in any other sections other than section 5..  @AnatolyS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `select` max date for each student and `join` it back to the `student_history` table.

```
with maxdate as (
select student_id, max(date_entered) as mxdate 
from student_history
group by student_id)
select s.* 
from student_history s 
join maxdate m on s.student_id = m.student_id and s.date_entered = m.mxdate
where s.section_id in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some pretty challenging design flaws with your table but you can leverage ROW_NUMBER for this. This is not the best from a performance perspective but the suboptimal design limits what you can do. Please realize this is still mostly a guess because you haven't provided much in the way of details here.

```
with CurrentStudents as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by student_id order by date_entered desc) as RowNum
    from student_Queue_history
)
select *
from CurrentStudents
where section_id in (1, 2)
    and RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.student_id 
from student_Queue_history as a
where a.section_id in (1, 2) 
  and not exists (select b.student_id from student_Queue_history as b where b.student_id = a.student_id and b.Date_entered > a.Date_entered)
```